# np.array - too many values to unpack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a script to save a part of an image ("submatrix" in the code, reported below) as a tif file. When I run the code, I got the following error:

```
height, width = np.array(submatrix.shape, dtype = float) / dpi
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

If instead of the submatrix I use a random matrix like np.random.random((10, 10)), everything runs fine. Do you spot what I am doing wrong?

Using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
```

Here's the code section where the error is:

```
submatrix = im[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max]
dpi = size_box
height, width = np.array(submatrix.shape, dtype = float) / dpi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time I run into this, I set the output to a single var and the inspect that var to see what's inside.

```
>>> blah = np.array(submatrix.shape, dtype = float) / dpi
>>> dir(blah)
```

98% of the time, I simply miscounted the array size. (i.e. X, Y, and Z) the other 2% is usually due to variable length arrays (which really suck).

Early on, I would never use sequence unpack on the same line as the declaration, just to make debugging easier. I then set a break point on the `height, width` line to see why it caused a problem.

```
blah = np.array(submatrix.shape, dtype = float) / dpi
height, width = blah
```

Comment: `dir(blah)`? Do you mean `len(blah)` or, since it's an array, `blah.shape`?

Comment: I checked and I was effectively messing up with the array size... well spotted!

Comment: @askewchan Yeah, you're right; len(), type(), dir().. etc.  Anything that tells me about blah.

Answer (score 6):

The error message tells you what the problem is. There are too many values to unpack. Clearly `submatrix.shape` has length greater than 2.

I cannot tell why that is so, since I don't know what `im` is. But take a look at the following output from the interactive prompt:

```
>>> height, width = np.array([1,2], dtype = float)
>>> height, width = np.array([1,2,3], dtype = float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Something like that is causing your problem with `submatrix` fulfilling the role that `[1,2,3]` does above.

If you strip away all the numpy, this is just a standard sequence unpacking error. The simplest example of that being:

```
>>> x, y = (1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

When you perform [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=unpack%20tuple#tuples-and-sequences), the sequences on left and right hand side of the assignment operator must have the same length.

Comment: Well, before anyone else says so, one could argue that the simplest example is probably `x, = 0, 0` but that felt a little too weird.