# Comparing a matrix with the corresponding image

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to check if I am correctly saving data from a matrix to an image file. To do so I am doing as follows:

1. I save the matrix as a tif image;
2. I read the image;
3. I compare the image elements with the matrix elements.

The image elements and the matrix elements are all different; is it because of some conversion reason? Should I change how I save the matrix, and how I load the image?

Here's my code:

```
filename = 'image_%03i_%03i.jpeg' % (index, peak)
rescaled = (255.0 / matrix.max() * (matrix - matrix.min())).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
im.save(filename)
#Now I read the image I just saved, and check if the values are effectively those of the matrix
im_1 = Image.open(filename)
im_1_check = im_1.load()
for i in range(0, ran_x, 1):
    for j in range(0, ran_y, 1):
        print rescaled[i,j], im_1_check[i,j]
```

Comment: Are you comparing with your rescaled image or your original image?

Comment: My plan is to compare the image with the data before rescaling ("matrix" in the code).

Comment: So you effectively compare your `matrix` with `rescaled` and expect the same values?

Comment: OK that was a mistake. I am now comparing data from the saved image `im_1_check` and `rescaled`, and there are still differences...

Comment: I made the correction in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the `rescaled` matrix with the saved image, you need to change the indexes and compare `rescaled[i,j]` with `im_1_check[j,i]`. Defining `diff = ndarray((ran_x,ran_y),int)`, the final part of the code above becomes

```
for i in range(0, ran_x, 1):
    for j in range(0, ran_y, 1):
        diff[i,j] = rescaled[i,j] - im_1_check[j,i]
        print rescaled[i,j], im_1_check[j,i], diff[i,j]
```

And the `diff` values are all zero.

Answer (score 0):

You're saving as a jpg in your code so you can expect different values due to the compression.  Try changing `filename = 'image_%03i_%03i.jpeg' % (index, peak)` to `filename = 'image_%03i_%03i.png' % (index, peak)` and see if that fixes things.

Also as noted in the comments you are comparing `im_1_check` to the original matrix not to `rescaled`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a format to suggest so to avoid compression problems?

Comment: Done. I still have that some of the values do not coincide.

Comment: That is odd. Could you add some example input data (e.g. dummy values for `matrix` that cause this problem) to your post?

Comment: This is how the typical column looks like: `[0, 0, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the data as runnable Python code? e.g. `matrix = np.array([[1, 2],[3,4]])` or whatever matches your actual `matrix` data? I'm not trying to be difficult but without a proper example it's very hard for people to help you with your problem. Otherwise it's mostly guesswork.

Comment: Hi, the original data are extracted from this image: http://cl.ly/1B3g0J0d1h2j. The region is 20x20, centred at (1349,75). This is the image I got by saving the rescaled data: http://cl.ly/image/1g1L160H2l3B

Comment: @albus_c I don't like to link to this too often but please read this short page http://sscce.org/ to understand what I am asking for and why. I'm asking for good reasons and in your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19724971/553404) people have made similar comments. You can easily paste some 20x20 input data into your question (or data from a smaller region if you like) or you could add random data (preferably with a fixed seed). Make it so we can paste this directly into a Python interpreter and see the problem. You'll get the right answer in no time that way.